# Skip login on MVC 3 application (SSO)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, single-sign-on, global-asax

I have an MVC application which is using forms authentication.
In the global.asax file, whenever trying to get into a site, you'll be redirected to login form:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

I also have another application which should call this application in an iframe. The iframe should have a link of one of my inner pages and shouldn't go through the login page (the other application sends the username, and then I have an authentication method), and get directly to the inner page, but I can't seem to get the url of the inner page.

I tried using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer but it appears null

How can I get this info and skip the login page?

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you change this route then?

Comment: Because normally it should go to login page, but in a specific case, it shouldn't

Comment: You can add conditions accordingly in that case in login action itself.

Comment: This is your default route. You can add as many other routes as you'd like. In reality, you should be using `[Authorize]` on the actions/controllers that you want to protect. Setting the route has no relevance to authentication. You should look at this to get a better understanding of routes: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC